# Vue.js Vuex unit test failing , [vuex] unknown getter:

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuex

I am testing my App.vue , and I am stuck with a Vuex error on getters...
I guess it's related to a badly define getters property , but I don't see how to solve it ..
feeedback welcome

**Console.log**

```
    ERROR LOG: '[vuex] unknown getter: getLists'
      App.vue
        ✗ calls store action addShoppingList when a click event is fired from the plus-sign icon
            AssertionError: expected false to equal true
                at Context.<anonymous> (webpack:///test/unit/specs/App.spec.js:33:50 <- index.js:24490:51)
```

**App.spec.js**

```
    import App from '@/App'
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    import sinon from 'sinon'
    import { mount } from 'avoriaz'
    Vue.use(Vuex)

    describe('App.vue', () => {
      let actions
      let getters
      let store

      beforeEach(() => {
        actions = {
          addShoppingList: sinon.stub(),
          populateShoppingLists: sinon.stub()
        }
        getters = {
          shoppinglists: () => 'getLists'
        }
        store = new Vuex.Store({
          state: {},
          actions,
          getters
        })
      })

      it('calls store action addShoppingList when a click event is fired from the plus-sign icon', (done) => {
        const wrapper = mount(App, { store })
        wrapper.find('a')[0].trigger('click')
        wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
          expect(actions.createShoppingList.calledOnce).to.equal(true)
          done()
        })
      })
```

**App.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div id="app" class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li :class="index===shoppinglists.length-1 ? 'active' : ''" v-for="(list, index) in shoppinglists"  :key="list.id"  role="presentation">
            <shopping-list-title-component :id="list.id" :title="list.title"></shopping-list-title-component>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" @click="addShoppingList">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div :class="index===shoppinglists.length-1 ? 'active' : ''" v-for="(list, index) in shoppinglists"  :key="list.id"  class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" :id="list.id">
            <shopping-list-component :id="list.id" :title="list.title" :items="list.items"></shopping-list-component>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      import ShoppingListComponent from './components/ShoppingListComponent'
      import ShoppingListTitleComponent from './components/ShoppingListTitleComponent'
      import store from './vuex/store'
      import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
      import _ from 'underscore'

      export default {
        components: {
          ShoppingListComponent,
          ShoppingListTitleComponent
        },
        computed: {
          ...mapGetters({ shoppinglists: 'getLists' })
        },
        methods: _.extend({}, mapActions(['populateShoppingLists', 'createShoppingList']), {
          addShoppingList () {
            let list = { title: 'New Shopping List', items: [] }
            this.createShoppingList(list)
          }
        }),
        store,
        mounted: function () {
          this.$nextTick(function () {
            this.populateShoppingLists()
          })
        }
      }
    </script>
```

**UPDATE**

here are my getters.js anf store.js files 
store.js is imported in App.vue

**store.js**

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    import getters from './getters' // import getters !
    import actions from './actions'
    import mutations from './mutations'

    Vue.use(Vuex)

    const state = {
      shoppinglists: []
    }

    export default new Vuex.Store({
      state,
      mutations,
      getters,
      actions
    })
```

**getters.js**

```
    import _ from 'underscore'

    export default {
      getLists: state => state.shoppinglists,
      getListById: (state, id) => {
        return _.findWhere(state.shoppinglists, { id: id })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define a `getLists` getter in your store. You're defining a `shoppinglists` getter that returns `'getLists'`.

You need to either change your `mapGetters` line to be:

```
...mapGetters(['shoppinglists'])
```

Or change the name of the getter to `getLists`:

```
getters = {
  getLists: () => 'getLists'
}
```

(Although I'm not sure if you are really meaning to return a string value in that getter or not)

Comment: thanks a lot.. FYI I added the store.js file (imported in App.vue) which import the getters.js file ( and also actions, mutations ) As you can see in the App.vue  computed props, I have shoppingLists which is returned by the getLists helper... shoppinglists is an Array bound to the template elements

Comment: Got it... you put me on tracks ...  During test execution, mapGetters(({ shoppinglists: 'getLists' }) in App.vue, is getting 'getLists' action from the mocked getters in the App.specs.js. So , I just have to define getLists: as a function returning the array...  see my own answer

Answer (score 2):

@thanksd put me on tracks...  see my comment

so I need to define the getters in my Vur.spec.js as following

```
    getters = {
      getLists: () => {
        // console.log('WE ARE S TEST')
        state => state.shoppinglists
      }
    }
```